# How do I find the right psychologist for myself?

Tags: social-psychology

Many psychologists resist disclosing their opinions on school prior to making an appointment.  I want to talk about my problems with being bullied in school, and I don't think that a therapist could help me unless they hated schools in general.  I have had a bad experience with a liberal psychologist who had a regular set of opinions surrounding schools.  How could I determine if a psychologist distrusts academia?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, you might be able to find a psychologist or a group practice who blogs specifically about bullying? That might a good way to find out the opinions and direction of how they would approach therapy with you. Unfortunately, there are no simple or easy ways to predict or decipher bias or the direction of the therapy. Usually it is worth visiting a couple of psychologists and decide after a couple of sessions?